# Can I use the word "where" as a Subordinating Conjunction which is not referring to a place or location?

Tags: word-choice

I'm about to finish writing a thesis on technical topics.
I'm contemplating, whether or not I'm using the word "where" correctly as a subordinating conjunction.

English is my second language.

Here are a couple of examples. I'll appreciate your response regarding the correctness of these sentences, as well as general information on the right usage of "where".

**Example 1:** 
Neglecting first its nonlinear effects, the fiber can be represented
by means of its frequency response
`(here comes an equation with variables that have to be determined)`,
where ω =2πf is the angular frequency in rad/s, α is the wavelength-dependent attenuation constant in Np/m, β ( ω ) is the phase constant in 1/m, and L is the length of the fiber (in m).

**Example 2:**
The fibers can be roughly separated into two types, namely a multi-mode fiber and a single-mode fiber (SMF) [19], where the latter is considered in the remaining of this chapter.

**Example 3:** 
The phase response shows that the amount of dispersion depends both on the fiber length and the signal bandwidth, where the impact of CD grows linearly with the transmission length, but quadratically with the signal bandwidth.

**Example 4:** 
Fig. 2.2 shows the received signal on the complex plane for the three different scenarios, where the symbol transitions are illustrated in gray and the Baud-rate sampled constellation points in blue.

**Example 5:** 
 The black dots denote the nodes of the network, and the blue lines are the connecting optical transmission links, where the investigated link path is highlighted in pink. (something tells me that in this case I should use "whereas" rather than "where"...).

**Example 6:**
It is also possible to consider the equalization problem as an estimation problem, where the estimation error between the equalized and the transmitted sequence has to be minimized.

I think you've got the point.

Many thanks in advance for your help

Roi

Comment: All of your examples sound fine to me. You seem to know your particularly field of study well, and know how your peers write, what formulations are the right jargon. In my experience, formulas (“where alpha denotes...”) and graphs (“where red dots represent...”) are commonly used as metaphorical places and can easily be modified by “where.”

Comment: @RichardZ thanks for your feedback. Interestingly, some people see this topic in a different light (see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/520650/can-i-use-the-word-where-as-a-subordinating-conjunction-which-is-not-referring) for example), which makes this a bit confusing for me as a non-native speaker. At least I'm now sure about the figures and equations as metaphorical places.